# Unable to set dependant drop down in google form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dependent drop-down list in Google form.
It should be working like this>>
Choose Country>>>>State>>>>City.

All of the choices should be linked in each other means when I choose country then I should be able to see the option of state and those state cities in the below boxes.
The values are inheriting from a google spreadsheet in this form. The reason why I have done that is to keep updating the values whenever require on the form directly from the spreadsheet (without making any changes in the form itself).
Now the problem is I am unable to create this drop down and not sure what would be further coding for the same.

```html
function updateForm(){
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("10zx_500WegcUAYJk1vvnRF3zYMAXk0BHfHrKejnIxM0");
   
  var CountryList = form.getItemById("1372435040").asListItem();
 
// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Country");

  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var namesValues = names.getRange(1, 1, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var Country = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)    
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      Country[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  CountryList.setChoiceValues(Country);
```

Comment: Telling people (who help you for free) to work harder because of you being late on your deadlines, doesn't really usually encourage anyone to help you.

Comment: Oh, Ya Man!!! I have got a warning letter as well as the deadline for the same. Still no help from any one side. :-(